# matching multiple column keywords from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

a content table

```
content_id | content                               |
-----------x---------------------------------------x
    1      | he is python and javascript developer |
```

and a keywords table

```
key_id | Keyword        | content_id |
-------x----------------x------------x
   1   | python         |     1      |
   2   | developer      |     1      |
   3   | javascript     |     1      |
```

And in python sqlite, a query is required to know that couple of keywords match from the same content

```
search_term = "python developer"
terms = search_term.split()          #['python','developer']

for term in terms:
    result = cursor.execute('''SELECT con.content_id FROM keywords AS key 
                               LEFT JOIN content as con
                               ON key.content_id = con.content_id 
                               WHERE key.keyword = ?''',(term))


Pseudocode : if i get content_id = 1,1 for more than two times returning  the content_id
```

Question: if multiple keywords match from the keyword table on same content, return content_id (s)

Answer (score 0):

This query counts how many matching keywords there are:

```sql
SELECT content_id,
       COUNT(*) AS kw_count
FROM keywords
WHERE Keyword IN ('python', 'developer')
GROUP BY content_id
```

To get only rows with multiple keywords, add a condition on the grouped column:

```sql
...
HAVING kw_count > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to get content_ids with no duplicates. Try this:

SELECT con.content_id 
FROM content AS con
WHERE content_id in (
    SELECT content_id
    FROM keywords AS key
    WHERE keyword = ?)